# Why doesn't Internet Explorer apply CSS to "invalid" elements?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This works in chromium (and I assume every other major browser)

-html-

```
<invalid></invalid>
```

-css-

```
invalid {
    color: red;
}
```

`<invalid>` represents an invalid element (not part of the html standard)

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/myhonor/4H7Hj/

But when I try this in IE, it doesn't work.

why is this and is there a way fix this (is it a DTD thing?)

Comment: What version of IE? What doctype?

Comment: Which version of IE?  Your trying to create a non-standard tag, non HTML5 compliant browsers will not render your custom tag properly.

Comment: `<invalid>` isn't a valid HTML tag. You can't blame IE for this one.

Comment: well I saw this problem in IE8

Comment: Of all the things to complain about with IE, complaining that it doesn't support invalid markup seems like an odd one ;)

Comment: @sachleen I know <invalid> isn't a valid tag. what i'm saying is that even if it's invalid other browsers will still recognize it, and allows me to apply css styling

Comment: @Samuel Not all browsers work the same way. I think IE does it right in this case, honestly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just the way Internet Explorer works, up to and including version 8. To fix it, just call `document.createElement` with the name of the invalid element:

```
document.createElement('invalid');
```

[Here's your updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/4H7Hj/1/) It's the same idea as all those HTML5 shivs you see. And, as everyone else has already suggested, writing valid HTML is usually the best solution :)

Comment: Thanks for an answer I can actually use.

Comment: Funny that an answer that explains why is useless to a question that asks why. Less useful, maybe, but not at all?

Comment: @BoltClock well in my question I asked if there was a way to fix this and I kind of got pissed at everyone saying I should just use valid html. I'm experimenting with the limits of html, I don't can that it's invalid.

Answer (score 5):

IE before version 9 doesn't automatically create DOM elements corresponding to any tags it doesn't recognize in the markup. This is the main reason why HTML5 elements don't work in older IEs, which require the HTML5 shiv to be included in order to work.

In this case, you're not even writing HTML5; you're writing your own markup language which is completely unrelated to HTML. The easiest way to fix this is to actually write HTML... or if you insist on making up your own tags, you have to create them manually as minitech demonstrates, but expect to wire them up entirely on your own.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Elements that aren't recognized by a browser as part of HTML are typically created as `HTMLUnknownElement` objects in the DOM (this includes IE9 and newer), which It is said is done for forward compatibility (c.f. HTML5). These objects have the basic properties of `HTMLElement`, but besides that there isn't much else to go on...</sub>